# Rails 4.1 and Compass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, compass-sass

The upgrade from rails 4.0.2 to 4.1.0 failed: "File to import not found or unreadable: compass".

After several attempts with no solution I recognized the server message: "Unsupported rails environment for compass" (i.e. the first line just after my input 'rails s thin').

What does it mean and is there a solution to this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By trial-and-error I found one solution. The main problem was gem 'compass-rails-2.0.alpha.0', which I reset to 1.1.7. Also important: gem sprockets should be reset to 2.11.0.